# Displaying file's uploading percentage (a variable) on sweetalert

Tags: javascript, php, html, django, ajax

How do we actually create a variable which is the file's uploading percentage on sweetalert? I'm using PyCharm as a platform and Django as a GUI framework.

I've actually look at several types of questions pertaining to Ajax, PHP and sweetalert (can't find a specific problem related to mine), and tried some of the to mix and match some of the solutions, unfortunately, none of them work.

As stated below is my curent code:

In **html**:

```
<form id='upload' method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="myFunction()"> {% csrf_token %}

<input name="datas" type="file" id="datas"/>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="btnform3" style="height:6%; width:75%"/>

</form>

<script>
function myFunction() {

    Swal.fire({
        title: 'Status:',
        text: 'Files Uploading...',
        imageUrl:'static/widget-loader-lg-en.gif',
        html: '<h3 id="status"></h3>',
        showConfirmButton: false,
        allowOutsideClick: false,
    })
}

function _(el) {
    return document.getElementById(el);
}

function uploadFile() {
    var file = _("datas").files[0];
    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("datas", file);
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
    ajax.open("POST","static/upload.php");
    ajax.send(formdata);
}

function progressHandler(event) {
    var percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
    _("status").innerHTML = Math.round(percent) + "% uploaded... please wait";
}

function completeHandler(event) {
    _("status").innerHTML = event.target.responseText;
}
```

In **upload.php**:

```
<?php

$fileName = $_FILES["datas"]["name"]; // The file name
$fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["datas"]["tmp_name"]; // File in the PHP tmp folder
$fileType = $_FILES["datas"]["type"]; // The type of file it is
$fileSize = $_FILES["datas"]["size"]; // File size in bytes
$fileErrorMsg = $_FILES["datas"]["error"]; // 0 for false... and 1 for true
?>
```

Any comments and solutions would be well appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone is wondering for the answer, this is it- remove myFunction() and add on to uploadFile()

```
function uploadFile() {
    var file = _("raw_mica_datas").files[0];
    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("raw_mica_datas", file);
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
    ajax.open("POST","static/upload.php");
    ajax.send(formdata);
    swal.fire({
        title: 'Status:',
        text: 'Files Uploading...',
        html: '<h3 id="status">',
        imageUrl:'static/InternetSlowdown_Day.gif',
        showConfirmButton: false,
        allowOutsideClick: false,
    })

}
```

Cheers :)